# Trimend (Date and Time)

Tags: c#

```
2014-01-02 08:18:21""
```

I am reading this column from an excel file, but I need to remove the `""` for it to be a valid date, this is my code below, please kindly advice.

```
n.RBank_Authorizer_date = DateTime.Parse(dRow[4].ToString()>TrimEnd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) that takes a `params char[]`:

```
str = str.TrimEnd('"');
```

or with your code:

```
n.RBank_Authorizer_date = DateTime.Parse(dRow[4].ToString().TrimEnd('"'));
```

Note that `dRow[4].ToString()` can throw an exception if the field can be null. I would use the strongly typed [`DatRow.Field` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field.aspx) that supports also nullable types.

```
n.RBank_Authorizer_date = DateTime.Parse(dRow.Field<string>(4).TrimEnd('"'));
```

By the way, if the `DataRow` already stores this datetime as `DateTime` you don't need to convert it to string and back to DateTime at all. You just have to use the correct type with `Field`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the Replacemethod from string:

```
var dateString = dRow[4].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
```

The "ToString" should not be needed, but just in case you are getting something different than a string :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if your all rows ends with `""`, you can specify this in your [custom date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  method like;

```
string s = @"2014-01-02 08:18:21""";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'""'",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```